# Having issue with inserting a entry into a Table using VB.net/Django/PostgreSQL

Tags: django, vb.net, postgresql

I am trying to insert a entry into a table but the server says this

```
column "Date" is of type date but expression is of type integer at character 131
```

This is the SQL statement I can also show the VB.net but it is a horrid mess.

```
INSERT INTO "Inventory_chemicalrecord"("Barcode","Action","Name_id","Building","Qty","Date") VALUES ('IEN0001','ADD',1,'Marcus',1,2013-07-10);
```

Here is the String that I am passing

```
mySQLString = "INSERT INTO "&Chr(34)&"Inventory_chemicalrecord"&Chr(34)&"("&Chr(34)&"Barcode"&Chr(34)& ","&Chr(34)&"Action"&Chr(34)& ","&Chr(34)&"Name_id"&Chr(34)& ","&Chr(34)&"Building"&Chr(34)& "," &Chr(34)&"Qty"&Chr(34)& ","&Chr(34)&"Date"&Chr(34)& ") VALUES ("& code & "," &Chr(39)& Action &Chr(39) & "," & Name_id & "," & Building & ","& OriginalQty & "," & CurDate & ");"
```

Sorry this is the only way I have found to do this if this is the wrong way to do this please inform me.

I have tried

```
Chr(39)&CurDate&Chr(39)
"'"&CurDate&"'"
```

and even set

```
CurDate = Chr(39)&CurDate&CurDate(39)
```

I keep getting EOF expected and Type & does not match String
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Isn't there some way to use bound parameters instead of string concatenation with your INSERT?

Comment: Is there any way of preparing statements / passing parameters in the framework you are using? It is the only way to do such queries properly.

Comment: I haven't a clue. I used the django queries to figure out what the SQL should be and then fiddled with that and using print statements until the string was what it should be then moved on to the next one. This is the first time that I've ever dealt with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear.

The date needs to be wrapped in quotes : `'2013-07-10'`

```
INSERT INTO "Inventory_chemicalrecord"("Barcode","Action","Name_id","Building","Qty","Date") VALUES ('IEN0001','ADD',1,'Marcus',1,2013-07-10);
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO "Inventory_chemicalrecord"("Barcode","Action","Name_id","Building","Qty","Date") VALUES ('IEN0001','ADD',1,'Marcus',1,'2013-07-10');
```

Comment: I thought it meant it was a Integer type. I tried that earlier but had no luck. Part of it is because I am passing it as a string to be parsed. Would you mind looking and seeing if you can spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: just wrap it in quotes. You should be fine. Also, would be very hard to guess what is wrong without knowing anything about the code.

Comment: @user2482595 In your query `2013-07-10` means `2013 minus 7 minus 10`. While `'2013-07-10'` meand a date in SQL (with proper date/time settings).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I just assumed since it said it was a date it would treat it as such. The more you know :b

Comment: @karthikr It is better to use explicit date conversion like `to_date('2013-07-10','YYYY-MM-DD')`. This way it will not throw error on different date/time settings.

Comment: I hardcoded to see if that was the issue. It was thanks :p. Now to figure out how to not hardcode it : P